# jquery image fade in

Tags: jquery, image, animation, carousel

I have a working jquery image carousel that I was building. It's mostly finished (just the increase button works): http://jsfiddle.net/2C8fy/7/

The only problem I'm facing is that when the image get appended it does not fade in. It just appears. I tried adding another slot on the right that was 0 opacity and then animating it to fade in but that didn't seem to work either. How can I animate that right slot image to make it appear like it is fading in? Here's what I have right now:

```
$('#basic_div').animate({          //slides the div with the images in it to the left.
            left: '-=40px'
        }, 300, function() {

        });

        left.animate({             //fade out effect for the left most image
            opacity: 0
        }, 300, function() {
            left.remove();         //gets rid of left most image after it becomes invisible.
            $('#basic_div').css({
                left: '0px'        //resets the div that contains the images
            });
        });


            middle.attr('id', 'left_slot');       //changes ids
            right.attr('id', 'middle_slot');


            $("#basic_div").append(newImgSL);
            newImgSL.attr('id', 'right_slot');
            newImgSL.animate({
                opacity: 100   //I thought this would make it fade in, but it still just appears.
            }, 300);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To `fadeIn()` an image, start with `display: none` or `.hide()` and `opacity: 1`.

Or you can set the initial opacity to 0 and use `fadeTo(3000, 1)`.

`fadeIn()` expects the image to be initially `display: none` with the opacity set to the final opacity.  It will then remember the final opacity, set the opacity to 0, make the image visible and then start animating the opacity.

`fadeTo()` just starts at the current opacity and fades to the newly specified opacity.

So, in your case, you could do this:

```
// set id and initial opacity
newImgSL.attr('id', 'right_slot').css("opacity", 0);
// put it into the page
$("#basic_div").append(newImgSL);
// fade to visible
newImgSL.fadeTo(300, 1);
```

Also, remember that opacity is a decimal number from 0 to 1.

Your code doesn't show where `newImgSL` comes from.  Remember that you also need to make sure that the image has finished loading before trying to fade it.